# How does one handle Item 57 on I-130 if the beneficiary lives in the US but has a foreign name?

Tags: immigration

On [USCIS I-130](https://www.uscis.gov/i-130), Part 4, Item 57, it asks for the name and foreign address.

However, my spouse is living in the US with me, so does not currently have a foreign address.

Should I just write the name in characters and leave the foreign address blank, or fill in our state in the Province field?

Comment: Form I-130? No one has any idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, I've added a link. Please let me know if you think this is the wrong stackexchange for this question; I'm much less familiar with what is within scope for the non-technical stackexchanges.

Comment: This might be better on [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), though I suspect it may not have a real home.

Comment: @TimLymington it's quite on topic at [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the name in characters as the form states and the address request in that part of the form is for the person's address, not necessarily a foreign address, so simply write in the address where the person resides.

Comment: Prompted by the other answer, I've looked at the form again, and the address was already requested in items 11 through 13.  So it does appear that 58 is specifically asking for foreign address in non-Roman letters, if applicable.  Although a strict reading of the instruction for that item would lead to the conclusion that a native speaker of Russian who lives in London should respond by transliterating the London address into the Cyrillic script, which is surely not an intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think the correct way to answer this question is if the beneficiary's name and/or address is in a non-Latin script, write it in its original script here.

So in this case, the beneficiary's name is in a non-Latin script, but the address isn't, so you should only fill in #57a-c, and leave #58a-f blank (or write something like "(in Roman letters)" in #58a).

Conversely, if your beneficiary's name is in a Latin script, but their address isn't (e.g. if they are currently in a foreign country that uses a non-Latin script), then I think #57a-c should be blank, but #58a-f should be filled.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this works for someone whose native language is customarily written in two scripts, one of which is derived from the Latin alphabet and the other is not?